Number Operator "Ordering" for Higher Order Bosonic Operators
I'm considering the algebra of a single harmonic oscillator where $[\hat{a},\hat{a}^\dagger]=\hat{\mathbb{I}}$. Typically, one is interested in normal, antinormal or symmetric ordering. I am attempting to do a Schrieffer-Wolff perturbation theory calculation and I have Hamiltonian terms of interest that contain $$[\hat{a}^{\dagger n},\hat{a}^n],\,\hat{a}^{\dagger n} \hat{a}^n \text{ and } \hat{a}^n \hat{a}^{\dagger n}.$$
I would like to express each of these terms strictly in terms of powers of the number operator, $\hat{a}^\dagger\hat{a}$, and the identity, i.e., $[\hat{a}^{\dagger n},\hat{a}^n]=c_n(\hat{a}^\dagger \hat{a})^n+ c_{n-1}(\hat{a}^\dagger \hat{a})^{(n-1)}+...+c_1\hat{a}^\dagger \hat{a} +c_I\hat{\mathbb{I}}$ and the same for the other expressions.
I am not good at combinatorics and don't have an idea where to look for help on this but what I have used so far are the following identities:
$$ [\hat{a}^{\dagger},\hat{a}^k]=-k\hat{a}^{(k-1)},\,
    [\hat{a},\hat{a}^{\dagger k}]=k\hat{a}^{\dagger (k-1)}$$
$$[\hat{O}_1...\hat{O}_n,\hat{O}_{n+1}]=\sum_{i=1}^n\left(\prod_{j<i}\hat{O}_j\right) [\hat{O}_i,\hat{O}_{n+1}]\left(\prod_{k>i}\hat{O}_k\right)$$
and using that we can also find
$$[\hat{O}_1...\hat{O}_n,\hat{O}_{n+1}...\hat{O}_{n+m}]=\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{l=n+1}^{n+m}\left(\prod_{j<i}\hat{O}_j\right)\left(\prod_{r<l}\hat{O}_r\right) [\hat{O}_i,\hat{O}_l]\left(\prod_{s>l}\hat{O}_s\right)\left(\prod_{k>i}\hat{O}_k\right) .$$
Using these identities together I can simplify the commutator a bit but I cannot rewrite it in powers of the number operator. I guess I am seeking a sort of number operator "ordering" for equal powers of creation and annihilation operators.
Any help is appreciated.

You've already cleaned up n=1,2,3,4... no?

Hint: You are familiar with $ag(N)= g(N+1) a$ for any function g. Start from
$$
a^\dagger f(N) a= f(N-1)  N,\\
a g(N) a^\dagger= g(N+1) ~~(N+1).
$$
But for
$$
a^{\dagger ~n} a^n\equiv f_n(N), \qquad f_1(N)=N\\
a^n a^{\dagger ~n} \equiv g_n(N),\qquad g_1(N)=N+1,
$$
it follows that
$$
f_n(N)= a^\dagger f_{n-1} a=f_{n-1}(N-1)N, \\
g_n(N)=ag_{n-1}(N) a^\dagger= g_{n-1}(N +1)~~(N+1)...
$$
Recursively, what do you conclude? (n=1,2,3,4...)

From these hints I deduced:
(1): $\hat{a}^{\dagger n}\hat{a}^n=\prod_{l=0}^{n-1}(\hat{a}^\dagger \hat{a} - l\mathbb{I})$
and
(2):$\hat{a}^n\hat{a}^{\dagger n}=\prod_{l=1}^{n}(\hat{a}^\dagger\hat{a} +l\mathbb{I})$

Yes, of course.
